# Unit testing for service in Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to create unit testing for service I have import data service in spec file.

Then I am calling  in beforeach Method.

```
 providers: [
    { provide: dataservice}    
  ],
```

I am getting this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setNumber' of undefined

this.dataService.setNumber(null);
```

As per the below user I added

```
const spyDataService = jasmine.createSpyObj('DataService', ['setNumber '])
```

in before each

How to get rid of this error I am trying like below i am getting error and i modifed this into

```
  it('should be create data service', () => {    
     expect(DataService).setNumber;
    });

  it('should be create data service', () => {
    expect(service.setBCNumber).toHaveBeenCalledWith(null);
  });
```

but still I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You must provide the class instead of the instance. if you want to provide a instance, you must use `useValue` like this:

```
{
  provide: DataService,
  useValue: dataServiceMock
}
```

Also, expect is on an instance, not a class, hence

```
expect(DataService).setNumber;
```

should be

```
expect(dataService.setNumber).toHaveBeenCalledWith(null);
```

You also need to set the dataServiceMock to a mock instance like in the example:

```
let dataServiceMock: jasmine.SpyObj<DataService>;

beforeEach(() => {
  const spyDataService = jasmine.createSpyObj('DataService', ['setNumber ']);

...
    {
      provide: DataService,
      useValue: spyDataService
    }
...
```

I recommand you the official angular site for testing:
https://angular.io/guide/testing-services

Comment: Hi @JFPicard I assigned the dataService after describe like this let service: DataService and I call this in the method that is expect(service).setnumber but I got some error property setnumber does not exist on type marchers<DataService>

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: Thanks for the reply but still iam getting same error this is what iam giving in  providers[{provide:DataService, useValue:{} }], and this is code expect(service.setNumber).tohaveBeenCalledWith(null)

Comment: This is the error Iam getting this.dataService.setNumber is not a function

Comment: You provide an empty implementation with useValue:{} You must add a real implementation with a setNumber function

Comment: You mean to say I need to provide a data like this in useValue:{23452}

Comment: thank you so much for your effort why there is two providers needed 

{
  provide: DataService,
  useValue: dataServiceMock
}

  {
      provide: DataService,
      useValue: spyDataService
    }

Comment: still I am facing the issue can you please help me here